# Calling Gnuplot in Swift

Tags: swift, gnuplot, nstask, nspipe

I'm trying to call gunplot from swift to produce some plots in `.png`. However, the program below does not work --- the resulting `1.png` file is empty. If I leave the "set term aqua" though, it does call the aqua window with the plot in it. However when I try to set output to file (png or pdf) the result is always an empty file.

The gnuplot commands are ok --- I can correctly run them manually.

```
import Foundation

let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/opt/local/bin/gnuplot"
task.currentDirectoryPath = "~"

let pipeIn = NSPipe()
task.standardInput = pipeIn
task.launch()

let plotCommand: NSString =
  "set term png\n" +
  "set output \"1.png\"\n"
  "plot sin(x)\n" +
  "q\n"

pipeIn.fileHandleForWriting.writeData(plotCommand.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

I'm new both to swift and pipes, so please tell me if there is something wrong or unrecommended with the code.

Comment: I don't know `swift` but if I were you I can try: 1. to add a newline after the filename `"set output \"1.png\"\n"` (you miss __\n__). 2: to close the file in gnuplot adding something like `"set output \n "`  before `"q\n"`.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Hastur no, neither helped.

Comment: I hoped... Just that you fixed let we put even a + :-) `"set output \"1.png\"\n" +` (we miss +). Again let me know...

Comment: @Hastur omg!! that's it! `\n` and `+` were missing, not it works. I think you can make an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often is easy to miss a simple sign when we concatenate strings.
In this case you can fix adding `\n` and `+` to the line with `set output`:

```
 "set output \"1.png\"\n" +
```

The idea is to create a string as if we were writing in the `gnuplot` shell, so with each`\n` we are simulating a new line and with each `+` we concatenate two or more strings...
this is even the idea that underlie the *gnuplot scripting*...

Often with `gnuplot` is cosy to write an external script and to load it with

```
  load "myscript.gnuplot"
```

or running it with

```
 gnuplot -persist myscript.gnuplot
```

In this way you will have always the possibility to redo your plot or analysis  in a blink of an eye, and your result will be always reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.4**

```swift
let commandString: String =
    """
    set terminal png
    set output 'FIND_ME_01.png'
    plot sin(x)
    quit\n
    """

func plot() {
    let argv: [String] = ["--persist"] // do not close interactive plot
    let task = Process()
    task.arguments = argv
    //                "/opt/homebrew/bin/gnuplot" // Big Sur, Apple Silicon
    task.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/gnuplot"    // Big Sur, Intel
    // where to find the output
    let homeDir = FileManager.default.homeDirectoryForCurrentUser
    task.currentDirectoryURL = homeDir.appendingPathComponent("Desktop")


    let pipeIn = Pipe()
    task.standardInput = pipeIn
    let pipeOut = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipeOut
    let pipeErr = Pipe()
    task.standardError = pipeErr
    
    do {
        try task.run()
        let commandData = commandString.data(using: .utf8)!
        pipeIn.fileHandleForWriting.write(commandData)
        
        let dataOut = pipeOut.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        if let output = String(data: dataOut, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("STANDARD OUTPUT\n" + output)
        }

        let dataErr = pipeErr.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        if let outputErr = String(data: dataErr, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("STANDARD ERROR \n" + outputErr)
        }
    } catch {
        print("FAILED: \(error)")
    }
    task.waitUntilExit()
    print("STATUS: \(task.terminationStatus)")
}
```

Current Swift `"""` syntax allows for a multi-line string literial. This avoid then need for string concatenation.

*Note: The `commandString` needs to terminate with a newline. An ending extra blank line is needed if `\n` is not used at the end.*

```swift
quit\n
"""
```

```swift
quit

"""
```